# How to add non-empty values from two tables in mySQL DB using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables inside a mysql database. **table_1** and **table_2**

Both of these tables have 4 columns for users

> user_1, user_2, user_3 and user_4

[image]

[image]

Now using PHP I first want to fetch the non-null values from two tables and I use this query.

```
<?php
$query1 = "

select * from table_1 where user_1!='' and user_1 is not null 
union all

select * from table_1 where user_2!='' and user_2 is not null 
union all

select * from table_1 where user_3!='' and user_3 is not null 
union all

select * from table_1 where user_4!='' and user_4 is not null 
    
";
```

Then I fetch it and count the entries total = **mysqli_num_rows** and it gives me correct details as 3.

Similarly  I do it for table_2

```
<?php
    $query2 = "
    
    select * from table_2 where user_1!='' and user_1 is not null 
    union all
    
    select * from table_2 where user_2!='' and user_2 is not null 
    union all
    
    select * from table_2 where user_3!='' and user_3 is not null 
    union all
    
    select * from table_2 where user_4!='' and user_4 is not null 
        
    ";
```

and it shows me total count as 2 which is correct.

But when I add count1 and count2

```
$count1 = mysqli_num_rows($data1);
$count2 = mysqli_num_rows($data2);

$total = $count1+$count2;
```

It shows either 1 or some weird value.Please suggest a fix

Comment: The code as you have described it won't produce the result you claim. Please post the actual code that delivers this result.

Comment: First let's just say that's a really weird data structure and it probably isn't helping your issue. What are these tables representing, why did you design them with the same data item in multiple different columns and tables? It's pretty much the first rule of database design that you don't do that because it causes issues.

Answer (score 2):

Everything depends on what `$data1` and `$data2` is. If they contain the results of `$query` and `$query2`, respectively, then one could expect the result to be 5. However, since your result is different, it follows that `$data1` and `$data2` is not what you think. So, in order to find out what the problem is, you will need to find out what `$data1` and `$data2` is. You will need to `var_dump` them and analyze what their value is, detect the nature of the anomaly. Once that's done, you will need to look at the code and figure out how that value was ending up into your variables.

Answer (score 2):

to getting which column is not empty, you should add some condition as `AND` and if your fields have whitespace please consider `TRIM` condition such as:

```php
SELECT * FROM `table_1` WHERE `user_1` IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(column) <> '' union all
```

notice: if you want use more than one command in php variable as string, you should add semicolon on end of each command

```php
$query ="
SELECT * FROM `table_1` WHERE `user_1` IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(user_1) <> '' union all;

SELECT * FROM `table_2` WHERE `user_2` IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(user_2) <> '' union all;

SELECT * FROM `table_3` WHERE `user_3` IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(user_3) <> '' union all;
"
```